# Tomar datos de un dataForm enviado mediante ajax, en un servlet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

Estoy enviando un archivo y un parametro mediante ajax atravez de un dataForm, pero no logro obtener esos datos en el servlet, ni usando el request para el parametro que es un texto.
Asi envio los datos mediante ajax

```
    var modulo = "subirArchivo";
    var archivo = new FormData();
    archivo.append("archivo",$("#documentoPersonal")[0]);
    archivo.append("modulo",modulo);

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../ServletMainController",
    data: archivo,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (msg) {

    },
    error: function (msg) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Saludos Jeisson, de casualidad ¿Has visto las preguntas parecidas?

Comment: Esta se parece muchísimo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/32462/822

Comment: No me sirve porque yo estoy enviando un archivo y un parámetro por el dataform pero no se como separar los datos para recibir cada uno aparté

Comment: Entiendo, ¿Has visto las preguntas parecidas?

Comment: Algunas pero no he dado con la solución que necesito

Comment: @Jeisson Hernandez puedes poner error que te esta dando el log